# Excel VBA - cancel cut and paste code is not allowing to copy and paste from an workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this vba code below, in Excel, to stop users from doing cut and paste and breaking formulas reference. The code itself works fine but it is creating an advert issue. The user will not be able to copy data from the workbook onto another workbook. Is there a work around it? Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Select Case Application.CutCopyMode

Case Is = False
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCopy
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCut

MsgBox "Please DO NOT Cut and Paste as it will break the formula reference." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
& "Use Copy and Paste, then delete the source.", vbCritical
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard and cancel cut

End Select
```

Comment: Did you try doing it in "ThisWorkbook" ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the code on the copy event, you need to handle the paste event. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim UndoList As String

  'Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
  UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

  
  If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then
    Application.Undo
    MsgBox "Please DO NOT Cut and Paste as it will break the formula reference." 
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Use Copy and Paste, then delete the source.", vbCritical
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried putting the code on ThisWorkbook but it did not work. Then I put the code on Sheet1 but it gives me a Run-time error '9'.  Another issue that I can see is that your code seems to not allow users do paste at all. User should be allowed to "copy and paste" but not allowed to "cut and paste". The original code is working fine, users cannot "cut and paste" but they can "copy and paste" within the workbook. The issue we are facing is that users are not able to "copy and paste" from one workbook to another workbook.